# Shortcut for destructuring items from multiple indexes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, destructuring

Given an array of less than 160 items, I want to extract three fields and make a copy of them;

```
 const item1 = {name:'Item-1'};
  const item2 = {name:'Item-1'};
  const item1 = {name:'Item-1'};
  ...........
  const item_N_minus_one = {name:'Item-N_minus_one'};
  const item_N = {name:'Item-N'};
  
  const itemsList = [{item1}, {item2} ..... upto {itemN}]
  
  // Where n <= 160
```

Below is my approach which is working

```
const index_X = 23, index_Y = 45, index_Z= 56; // Can not exceed beyond 160 in my case
  
  const item_XCopy = {...itemsList[index_X]};
  const item_YCopy = {...itemsList[index_Y]};
  const item_ZCopy = {...itemsList[index_Z]};
```

**What I want** : Looking for a one liner shortcut solution where I can pass indexes in one javascript statement and return fields in another array(I know I can make a function, but just wondering if there is a javascript shortcut solution)

Comment: You cannot use destructuring assignment to both take an item off somewhere *and* clone it. Destructuring does not work that way - it's merely a shortcut to get properties off somewhere, e.g., `const { bar } = foo;` is the shorter version of `const bar = foo.bar`. You don't *also* manipulate the property on assignment.

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what the output value should be. If you want three objects in three different variables then what you have seems ok.

Comment: pretty sure a function *is* a 'javascript shortcut solution'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the items, not copies, like this:

```js
const itemsList = [{name:'Item-1'}, {name:'Item-2'}, {name:'Item-3'}];
const index_X = 0, index_Y = 1, index_Z= 2;

const { [index_X]: index_X_Item, [index_Y]: index_Y_Item, [index_Z]: index_Z_Item } 
  = itemsList;

console.log(index_X_Item, index_Y_Item, index_Z_Item);
```

To get copies, you can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const itemsList = [{name:'Item-1'}, {name:'Item-2'}, {name:'Item-3'}];
const index_X = 0, index_Y = 1, index_Z= 2;

const [index_X_Copy, index_Y_Copy, index_Z_Copy] = 
  [index_X, index_Y, index_Z].map(index => ({ ...itemsList[index] }));

console.log(index_X_Copy, index_Y_Copy, index_Z_Copy);
```

Comment: but the question seems to be specifically about cloning

Comment: Would it not clone the objects ?

Comment: no, it doesn't clone the objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could address directly and [assign to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).

```
const
    index_X = 23,
    index_Y = 45,
    index_Z = 56,
    {
        [index_X]: { ...item_XCopy },
        [index_Y]: { ...item_YCopy },
        [index_Z]: { ...item_ZCopy }
    } = itemsList;
```

Comment: these won't be copies, but still just references

Comment: @pilchard, it take the nesred object. should it be unwrapped?

Comment: I couldn't tell if the `[{item1, item2 ...}]` notation in the question was a typo or not. Is it an array with a single object in it? or an array of objects? I voted to close for clarity

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz, You have showed the way , but I could have accepted only one answer. Thanks again for the trick

Comment: @pilchard, Thanks for letting know mistake, I have just edited the  question.